Does LinkedIn have an API that would allow a user to get the posts in their live feed?
I have a client who would like to have an automated process that would read the posts of people/organizations he is following and look for key words in those posts.  Is this possible?  I understand for most of the LinkedIn APIs there is a vetting/approval process that would be required, but at the moment I am just trying to work out if this is even feasible.

The Posts API that is available has some post retrieval methods, such as:

Batch Get Posts
Find Posts by Authors
Find Posts by Account

Then after retrieving the posts you could apply the filters you need
Documentation: Post Api

Other than this is being deprecated, it doesn't seem to have the functionality needed.  It can be used to follow the posts of another account, but not the post feed into his own account which is what he is looking for.  ie.  It's the opposite side of what is wanted.
